# How to implement cross_val_score with BayesianRidge using an unsupervised learning?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, bayesian

I am new with `sklearn`.
My objective is to estimate the score of a dataset using `cross_val_score` with  `BayesianRidge` estimator. It should be implemented using an `unsupervised learning`. The code below is taken from `sklearn` except that the `target variable`, `y`, is excluded.
The data is taken `from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing`.

```
estimator = BayesianRidge()
score_full_data = pd.DataFrame(cross_val_score(br_estimator, X=X, y=None, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=5), columns=['Data'])
```

I got a `TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`.
The expected result is:

```
Data
0   -0.408433
1   -0.636009
2   -0.614910
3   -1.089616
4   -0.407541
```

How is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because of the fact that you are using a `supervised` learning classifier and trying to use it as an `unsupervised` classifier. You can't simply expect the underlying implementation of `BayesianRidge` classifier to change just because you are not supplying the `target` variable, i.e. `y`. If you check the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.BayesianRidge.html#sklearn.linear_model.BayesianRidge.fit), you will see that `y` is not an optional argument. Image from the link for reference:

[image]
[Image Source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.BayesianRidge.html#sklearn.linear_model.BayesianRidge.fit)

Secondly, this is not an unsupervised learning problem in the first place. This dataset you mentioned is for regression. So it doesn't make sense to use unsupervised learning here.

Comment: Thanks, @Mohammed Kashif. 
The original problem was because I don't have the ```variable vector```, ```y.``` I only have the raw data, ```X```. Is it correct if I build the ```y``` from ```X``` using ```train_test_split()``` function?

Comment: @k.ko3n No that would still be incorrect. You cannot build `y` from `X`. Are you still using the housing dataset you mentioned in the question above ?

Comment: I used the example and data in the question for learning only. For my actual task, I am using my data, but only ```X``` is available. I don't know how or where to get the ```y```.

Comment: @k.ko3n Can you give more details about the dataset ? Not the values, but only information about columns and what problem you are trying to solve. From what I understand, you need to use an unsupervised classifier in this case, but I need more clarification in order to help you out further. It would be better, if you could post these details as a seperate question and I can help you out there.

Comment: I have rephrased the problem in a new post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57154209/implementation-of-sklearn-impute-iterativeimputer. Thanks for your attention.