# Implementation of sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn, missing-data, imputation

Consider `data` which contains some nan below:

```
Column-1    Column-2    Column-3    Column-4    Column-5
0   NaN 15.0    63.0    8.0 40.0
1   60.0    51.0    NaN 54.0    31.0
2   15.0    17.0    55.0    80.0    NaN
3   54.0    43.0    70.0    16.0    73.0
4   94.0    31.0    94.0    29.0    53.0
5   99.0    52.0    77.0    91.0    58.0
6   84.0    19.0    36.0    NaN 97.0
7   41.0    91.0    62.0    67.0    68.0
8   44.0    38.0    27.0    53.0    37.0
9   58.0    NaN 63.0    57.0    28.0
10  66.0    68.0    89.0    36.0    47.0
11  7.0 81.0    5.0 99.0    16.0
12  43.0    55.0    64.0    88.0    NaN
13  8.0 90.0    91.0    44.0    4.0
14  29.0    52.0    94.0    71.0    47.0
15  22.0    21.0    68.0    61.0    38.0
16  76.0    36.0    70.0    99.0    50.0
17  38.0    31.0    66.0    79.0    99.0
18  94.0    22.0    92.0    39.0    58.0
```

I want to replace nan in the `data` using `sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer`. A friend helped me with the code below:

```
imp = IterativeImputer(missing_values=np.nan, sample_posterior=False, 
                                 max_iter=10, tol=0.001, 
                                 n_nearest_features=4, initial_strategy='median')
imp.fit(data)
imputed_data = pd.DataFrame(data=imp.transform(data), 
                             columns=['Column-1', 'Column-2', 'Column-3', 'Column-4', 'Column-5'],
                             dtype='int')
```

The `imputed_data` is:

```
Column-1    Column-2    Column-3    Column-4    Column-5
0   59  15  63  8   40
1   60  51  66  54  31
2   15  17  55  80  48
3   54  43  70  16  73
4   94  31  94  29  53
5   99  52  77  91  58
6   84  19  36  59  97
7   41  91  62  67  68
8   44  38  27  53  37
9   58  46  63  57  28
10  66  68  89  36  47
11  7   81  5   99  16
12  43  55  64  88  47
13  8   90  91  44  4
14  29  52  94  71  47
15  22  21  68  61  38
16  76  36  70  99  50
17  38  31  66  79  99
18  94  22  92  39  58
```

From the `IterativeImputer` [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer.html#sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer), the default estimator is `BayesianRidge()`. But if I use other estimators such as `estimator=ExtraTreesRegressor(n_estimators=10, random_state=0)` like in the code below, it returns a warning message.
The code:

```
imp = IterativeImputer(estimator=ExtraTreesRegressor(n_estimators=10, random_state=0), missing_values=np.nan, sample_posterior=False, 
                                 max_iter=10, tol=0.001, 
                                 n_nearest_features=4, initial_strategy='median')
imp.fit(data)
```

The message:

```
C:\Users\...\sklearn\impute\_iterative.py:599: ConvergenceWarning: [IterativeImputer] Early stopping criterion not reached. " reached.", ConvergenceWarning).
```

My question: is this a correct approach or should I do something to fix the warning message?
Thank you.

Comment: Was this ever resolved??

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this error because of the parameters `max_iter=10` & `tol=0.001`set for `IterativeImputer()`.

The stopping criterion (`abs(max(X_t - X_{t-1}))/abs(max(X[known_vals])) < tol`) is not met for 10 number of iterations(`max_iter=10`).

Refer to the description of `max_iter` in the parameters section of `sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer` [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer.html#sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer).

One workaround to overcome this error is setting the `max_iter` parameter value higher.

Answer (score 3):

They are having the same issue here:

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/14338

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to avoid errors due to NaN values, you can use the following line:

```
   missing_data = missing_data.replace(' ', np.nan)
```

To solve the problem of filling missing data and make it work with the available features, we did the following:

```
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("D:\\documents\\8thSemester\\MachineLearning\\1stPartial\\project1stPartial\\housing_in_london_yearly_variables_no_missing.csv")
missing_data_1 = pd.read_csv("D:\\documents\\8thSemester\\MachineLearning\\1stPartial\\project1stPartial\\housing_in_london_yearly_variables_normal.csv")
missing_data = missing_data_1[missing_data_1.isnull().any(axis=1)]
missing_data = missing_data.replace(' ', np.nan)

# Create an imputer that uses linear regression to estimate missing values
imputer = IterativeImputer(estimator=LinearRegression())

# Fit the imputer to your complete data
imputer.fit(data)

# Transform your data with missing values
missing_data_imputed = imputer.transform(missing_data)

# 'missing_data_imputed' is a numpy array, so you can convert it back to a DataFrame if needed
missing_data_imputed = pd.DataFrame(missing_data_imputed, columns=missing_data.columns)

# Save the DataFrame to a CSV file
missing_data_imputed.to_csv('missing_data_imputed.csv', index=False)
# Now, 'missing_data_imputed' is your original DataFrame, but with missing values filled in with the imputer's predictions
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to import ExtraTreesRegressor first. It should work fine.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor.
```

Also check for the version of scikit learn. It should be 0.21.1 and above.

Comment: I did import that